# Get invalid date when use date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I was using `date-fns` library and have the following code:

```js
 isSameMonth(parse('17. 3. 2021 17:44', 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()), new Date())
```

but it returns false which is wrong. But to test it out more I tried executing

```js
console.log(parse('17. 3. 2021 17:44', 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()))
```

and it returns "Invalid date"

No idea why

Comment: The `.` on the date seems weird to me, did you verify that it is an accepted format?

Answer (score 0):

The date you are parsing has to match the date format you say you are parsing.

`'17. 3. 2021 17:44'` isn't remotely like `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

This works when I test it in Node.js (but I can't persuade it to work in the browser with date-fns hosted on a CDN):

```
console.log(parse('17. 3. 2021 17:44', 'd. M. yyyy HH:mm', new Date()));
```

Do read the [the documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.19.0/docs/parse).

Answer (score 0):

You would need the following:

```
console.log(parse('17. 3. 2021 17:44', 'dd. MM. yyyy HH:mm', new Date()))
```

and

```
const sameMonth = isSameMonth(parse('17. 3. 2021 17:44', 'dd. MM. yyyy HH:mm', new Date()), new Date())
console.log(sameMonth)
```

Comment: Doesn't MM require a leading zero on the month?

Comment: I thin date-fns is `smart` to figure that out

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle, hi, sorry but I get "Invalid time value"(

Comment: @qweeee Are you getting invalid time for the same data as above. I'm getting true as per above code